# jquery function for 2 events

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following jquery, it works when I finish typing a value (keyup) in a textbox:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var minTenderNum;
    $("#tenmoney").keyup(function(){
        var minTenderMoney = $(this).val();
        if(minTenderMoney <=1000)
            minTenderNum = 3;
        else if(minTenderMoney > 1000)
            minTenderNum = 5;

        $('#sunum').children().remove().end();
        maxTenderNum = minTenderNum + 4;
        for(var i=minTenderNum;i <=maxTenderNum;i++)
        $('#sunum').append(new Option(i, i, true, true));

        $("#uniform-sunum>span").html('');
    });
});
</script>
     <select id="sunum" name="sunum">
     </select>
```

sometimes, a value already exists when the page is onload, but I have to modify the value and "key up" so that the function starts again.

If I wish to include an event for on load, how shall I modify the function? Thanks!

Comment: You're using an anonymous function for the event handler, simply strip out the function, give it a name then invoke it directly (update to do not use this but the eventObject). This won't make any trouble if something else will be attached to the keyup event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the ways to do this is On document ready You can fire a keyup event like this

```
$("#tenmoney").trigger('keyup');
```

add this line inside document ready callback

```
$(function(){

});
```

or even beter just call [$.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) without any argument which will trigger keyup event on that element like this

```
$("#tenmoney").keyup();
```